What's the contrary of formation as in the opposite of the process of formation?
What is a better term to refer to the opposite movement of something forming? That would be the process of something already formed going "backwards". Is there a word more precise for this than: deforming, un-forming, dissolving, or de-shaping?
Deforming appears to be the more logical orthography but It seems to me that it is usually used when some shape is turned into a "lesser" shape, an imperfect shape or even an uglier shape of what it should be. Not a process into which a shape "de-shapes", so to say.
The context is social processes like state formation.

What's the context? Could you give an example sentence?

Yes, we need to know what is forming or "goes backwards".

The context are social processes like state formation.

Not every antonym reverses its opposite the same way, just as most synonyms don't replace their partner every time.

dissolution

noun

the closing down or dismissal of an assembly, partnership, or official body:
"the dissolution of their marriage"

[Oxford Languages]

See more definitions from Merriam-Webster.

+1 but here’s a more robust definition, from the OED: 7. The breaking up, dismissal, or dispersion of an assembly or association; the termination of the existence of a constituted body of persons (e.g. of the monasteries, and now esp. of Parliament).

I prefer this answer because it doesn't necessary connotes something negative, damaging or event violent so it can be used as a "neutral" term without involving judgement.

Also the word dissolution suggests that the constituent parts are still there although not together.

Thanks for comments and definition.

The first thought I had was disintegration, but hesitated to answer because the lack of context. Now that you have added that

The context are social processes like state formation.

I will suggest my first thought as an answer, since this is the political term used specifically for states (dissolution is also used).
Studysmarter explains:

Disintegration of States: A condition whereby nation-states cease to exist because devolution of powers has failed to preserve unity in their constituent territories, leading to a breakup. Disintegration can be peaceful, via independence referendums, or violent, via secession and civil war.

The Preparatory Document Drafted by the International Committee of the Red Cross for the First Periodical Meeting on International Humanitarian Law,( Geneva, January 19-23, 1998; original document in French) speaks of the disintegration of State structures and says:

Under international law, a State is an entity that has a defined territory and a permanent population, under the control of its own government, and that engages in, or has the capacity to engage in, formal relations with other such entities.
The disintegration of State structures seems to occur when the third constitutive element of statehood, a government in effective control, fades away.


Thank you. Even though the explanation you gave for disintegration of states describes it as a process that can be peaceful, I think the word disintegrate has a connotation of a sudden process that leaves no trace. Dissolution still may mean that the constituent parts are still there although not together. I still upvoted your answer.

A term for this with political overtones, which is what the original poster is mainly looking for would be Balkanization.
According to Britannica:

The division of a multinational state into smaller ethnically homogeneous entities. The term also is used to refer to ethnic conflict within multiethnic states. It was coined at the end of World War I to describe the ethnic and political fragmentation that followed the breakup of the Ottoman Empire, particularly in the Balkans. (The term Balkanization is today invoked to explain the disintegration of some multiethnic states and their devolution into dictatorship, ethnic cleansing, and civil war.)
Balkanization has occurred in places other than the Balkans, including Africa in the 1950s and ’60s, following the dissolution of the British and French colonial empires there. In the early 1990s the disintegration of Yugoslavia and the collapse of the Soviet Union led to the emergence of several new states—many of which were unstable and ethnically mixed—and then to violence between them.


Thank you. The problem with this term is that it refers to a particular historical event which for describing that event is fine but it may be problematic and less accurate to use it in a different setting or context.
